# Crosstab with mean() not working on Decimal objects

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, crosstab

I want to use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to calculate the `mean()` of sub groups. The values are of type [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects).

As you can see in my example it seems that `decimal.Decimal` doesn't work in that case. Is there a way to make it work without converting `Decimal` to another type?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import decimal
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'foo': list('AABB'),
    'bar': list('XYXY'),
    'val': [1.4, 6.2, 7, 87.12]})

# create Decimal instead of Float
df.val = df.val.apply(lambda x: round(decimal.Decimal(x), 4))

print(df)

tab = pandas.crosstab(
    index=df.foo,
    columns=df.bar,
    values=df.val,
    aggfunc='mean')

print(tab)
```

The output is

```
  foo bar      val
0   A   X   1.4000
1   A   Y   6.2000
2   B   X   7.0000
3   B   Y  87.1200

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [A, B]
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand if this is a bug or not.

But the solution is to use Pythons own [`statistics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) which can handle `Decimal`. See the modification of the `aggfunc` argument.

```
import statistics
# ...

tab = pandas.crosstab(
    index=df.foo,
    columns=df.bar,
    values=df.val,
    aggfunc=statistics.mean)
```